# Tkinter, Convertir Texto de Entry a variable en Python 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hola estoy haciendo un codificador de texto con una interfaz grafica hecha en Tkinter

Y necesito convertir el texto de un Entry de tkinter ¿Como lo hago?

este es mi codigo:

```
#Ticua cipher gui

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Ticua cipher gui (TCG)")

root.resizable(0,0)

root.geometry("480x480")
############################################
text = StringVar()

entry = Entry(root, textvariable=text)

entry.place(x=50, y=50)
############################################
w = Label(root, text=text)
w.pack()
############################################

root.mainloop()
```

lo que hace es poner un Entry y poner lo que haya en el entry a texto (que tengo que poner el entry en la variable y no puedo) en un Label

PD:El codificador ya lo hice solo lo tengo que portar en mi codigo despues de que se pueda mostrar el valor del entry, Para poder codificarlo y despues pegarlo en un label

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que usas el argumento incorrecto del constructor de `tkinter.Label`. El argumento `text` espera una cadena de caracteres (`str`), al pasar una instancia de `StringVar` simplemente intenta usar la salida del método `__str__` (o `__repr__` en su defecto) del objeto, lo mismo que si haces `print(text)`.

Al igual que haces con el `Entry`, para asociar una `StringVar` a un `Label`, debes usar el argumento `textvariable` y no `text`. Esto hará que al modificar la `StringVar` el texto del `Label` se modifique automáticamente de inmediato:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Ticua cipher gui (TCG)")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.geometry("480x480")

text = tk.StringVar(root)
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=text)
entry.place(x=50, y=50)

w = tk.Label(root, text=text)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Si quisieras que el texto del `Entry` se viera automáticamente en el `Label` a medida que se escribe pero pasando por alguna función que lo modifique (como "cifrarlo" desplazando letras), puedes hacer uso del método [`trace`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm):

```
import tkinter as tk

SHIFT = 3

def cesar(*args):
    new = []
    for char in entry_var.get():
        if char.isalpha():
            cod = ord(char) + SHIFT
            if cod > ord('z'):
                cod -= 26
            new.append(chr(cod))
        else:
            new.append(char)
    label_var.set("".join(new))


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Ticua cipher gui (TCG)")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.geometry("480x480")

entry_var = tk.StringVar(root)
label_var = tk.StringVar(root)
entry_var.trace("w", cesar)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var)
entry.place(x=50, y=50)
w = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_var)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Como nota aparte, te aconsejo que evites usar wildcard para importar (`from tkinter import *`) es una mala práctica general por múltiples razones, solo debe usarse en casos muy concretos (solapamiento intencionado de namespaces básicamente) y sabiendo perfectamente lo que hace.